# MariaDB field + 1

Tags: mysql, mariadb

How do I increase a field by +1 that was previously 0001 and then should be 0002?
I am currently using the following command:

```
SELECT fieldA+1
FROM table
WHERE ID = 1234;
```

But this only turns 0001 into 2

Its a very basic question but i dont get it

Comment: `0001` is not an integer but a string. you probably need to manipulate the string removing the leading 0s, adding 1 and then replacing the trailing 0s. Assuming that the leading 0s are to give the string a fixed length you can consider adding them only on the frontend instead of keeping them in the db

Comment: *How do I increase a field by +1 that was previously 0001 and then should be 0002?* On the one hand, you say that you want to increment the value which is stored in the column. On the other hand, you are showing a query that does not change the value of the column itself, but returns its incremented value. You will decide what exactly you need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A field of type `INT` must first be converted to a string (or `CHAR`) in order to perform string-based operations, such as a pad - albeit this may be taken care of 'under the hood' implicitly.

For example:

```
SELECT 
    LPAD(fieldA + 1, 4, '0') as fieldA_
FROM table
WHERE ID = 1234;
```

| fieldA_ |
| --- |
| 0002 |

Where the `LPAD` parameters are as follows: `LPAD(str, len [,padstr])`.

---

Related documentation:

- [String functions](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/string-functions/)
- [`LPAD`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/lpad/)

Aside:

- The designer must ensure the pad length is sufficient, otherwise characters *will be truncated*.
- It might be a consideration to leave 'formatting' activities to the front end, and leave the 'data' activities to the back end (i.e. database). Whichever approach you decide to take, *be consistent*. If/when this is updated, it can be frustrating to other developers and maintainers to not know exactly where to look when applying an update. (e.g. "Does this change apply to the database, or to the application?" is a question far too often asked.)
- **Take-away:** Given the potential complexity (review comments below) for getting the pad length correct - **just do the formatting in the application itself**. Let the database handle *data*, and the application handle *presentation*.

---

Edits:

- Addressed a comment stating a call to `CAST` is not required.
- Addressed a comment regarding string truncation.

Comment: Cast is unneeded, just `LPAD(fieldA + 1, 4, '0')` is enough

Comment: You must ensure that `fieldA + 1` contains not more than 4 digits (or 3 digits for negative value) - if not then excess trailing symbols will be truncated without notification.

Comment: @ysth - Interestingly, I originally tested without the CAST and it did not work. However, upon re-test - it's working. I must have done something wonky.  Thanks for the comment, updated.

Comment: to 0-pad up to 4 but not truncate if longer, `lpad(val, greatest(4,char_length(val)), '0')`

Comment: and if it may be negative, you need `if(val like '-%',concat('-', lpad(-val, 4-1, '0')),lpad(val, 4, '0'))`

Comment: so much easier to do formatting client-side :)

Comment: @ysth - Yes, absolutely! Have updated to refer to these comments. Cheers mate.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I increase a field by +1 that was previously 0001 and then should be 0002?

Use ZEROFILL column attribute accompanied by definite column length.

```
CREATE TABLE test ( id SMALLINT(4) ZEROFILL );
INSERT INTO test VALUES (1);
SELECT * FROM test;
```

| id |
| --- |
| 0001 |

```
UPDATE test SET id = id + 1;
SELECT * FROM test;
```

| id |
| --- |
| 0002 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/FCiDRsgg)

Comment: Note that MySQL (but not mariadb) has deprecated zerofill and display widths https://dbfiddle.uk/-0Du05RW